# Anyone have this autocompletion/syntax highlighting issue in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

While I'm coding, randomly the syntax highlighting stops working and same with the autocompletion in XCode 6.

If I close and reopen the project, it works again for a while, before the issue comes back within 5-15 mins.

Has anyone experienced this? How did you fix it?

I can't seem to identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen a few times while developing for Swift using Xcode6 and it gets worse the bigger your project gets. It seems like every new version improves on this issue but non of them has been able to fully fix for me. The only workaround I've found is to go to:

Window > Projects > Go to the derived data location for any of the projects and then delete the ModuleCache folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with XCode 7 GM and didn't have any luck with the DerivedData approach (besides freeing up some well-needed disk space), but did manage to track down the problem. For me, it was a line of code that was causing a) the syntax colouring to flicker on and off, and b) "segmentation fault: 11" on every build. By commenting out bits and pieces of the code, I found that it was this line causing the problem:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (newObjects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

I changed `newObjects` to be `[AnyObject]?` and both the segmentation fault and syntax colouring were fixed. (It's a method from the Parse API.)

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (newObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```